# Sorting values inside foreach

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to fetch each value and then display it in sorting order..

```
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){

    $simple_product_price = strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()));
    $simple_product_drink_size = $simple_product->getAttributeText('drink_size');       
    $simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
    $simple_product_name = $simple_product->getName();
    $simple_product_url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($simple_product);
    $updateUrl = str_replace('add','updateItemOptions',$simple_product_url);

    echo "<span class='product-attribute-elem product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."' title='".$simple_product_id."' >" . $simple_product_drink_size .
    "</span><input type='hidden' class='product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."-price' value='".
    $simple_product_price."'/><input type='hidden' class='product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."-url' value='".$simple_product_url."'/>".
    "<input type='hidden' class='product-attribute-".$simple_product_id."-name' value='".$simple_product_name."' >".
    '<span class="qtyUpdater-'.$simple_product_id.'" style="display:none">'.
    '<span onclick="NewAjaxAddCart(this,\''.$updateUrl.'\',\'-\',\'.category-products\');" class="Qmins">&nbsp;</span>'.
    '<input type="text" onchange="NewAjaxAddCart(this,\''.$updateUrl.'\',\'upd\',\'.category-products\');"  value="0" >'.
    '<span onclick="NewAjaxAddCart(this,\''.$updateUrl.'\',\'+\',\'.category-products\');" class="Qplus">&nbsp;</span></span>';
}
```

I want to sort and display the `$simple_product_id` as it is being fetched.. I tried tis

```
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
            $simple_product_price = strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()));
            $simple_product_drink_size = $simple_product->getAttributeText('drink_size');       
            $simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
            $sam_array[]=$simple_product_id;
            sort($sam_array);
    }
```

But its not working as expected.. So pls help me

Comment: isn't the $simple_product_price,$simple_drink size,$simple_product_id s are arrays?

Comment: whay you had expected?

Comment: @ferozakbar : They are not arrays.. It is a variable.. Each time d loop executes its value gets changed

Comment: Now i hav put up my full code.. Maybe now u can help me ? ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$simple_product_id = array();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        $simple_product_price = strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()));
        $simple_product_drink_size = $simple_product->getAttributeText('drink_size');       
        $simple_product_id[] = $simple_product->getId();
}
sort($simple_product_id);
```

If you want to display all the details.

```
$simple_product_array = array();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        $simple_product_price = strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()));
        $simple_product_drink_size = $simple_product->getAttributeText('drink_size');       
        $simple_product_id = $simple_product->getId();
        $simple_product_array[$simple_product_id] = array(
                                             'id' => $simple_product_id, 
                                          'price' => $simple_product_price, 
                                           'size' => $simple_product_drink_size);
}
ksort($simple_product_array);
```